# Stopping angular momentum to obtain a particular angle

Tags: algorithms, physics, rotations

While the overall project relates to software development, it boils down to a simple (i think) physics problem.

I have a joint (a motor, pretty much.) that needs to move to a specific angle. I can only adjust torque and speed. This of course adds some complexity, as it's hard to hit the correct angle, resulting in oscillation.

The way I see it, the variables involved are:

- $V$ - Angular velocity the joint is trying to achieve.
- $W$ - Actual angular velocity.
- $D$ - Distance to go (in radians) until target angle is achieved
- $Q$ - Motor torque
- $L$ - Angular momentum
- Did I miss any?

Any physics buffs or mechanical engineers who could tell me a formula that will allow me to adjust $Q$ and $V$ based on these variables, so that the joint will stop at the right place?

**PS:**

- If it makes it easier, the final angle won't have to be dead on. An error of ~$5$ degrees is acceptable.
- If possible, it is preferable to change torque as little as possible, and base this on adjusting $V$ instead.
- If $V$ is set to $0$, the joint will act as a break instead, with the same torque
- Things such as friction, air drag, and gravity can be ignored

Comment: You might consider posting this to the Physics Stack Exchange as well, since the audience there might be more mechanically inclined.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware that there was one specifically for physics. Cheers!